# Does aluminum darken when exposed to heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

My graphics card (3060Ti) got [these](https://ibb.co/LzQ315Y) markings that at first looked like mildew to me but after realizing this IO shield (the metal thing) is made of aluminum, I did some research and found out that apparently aluminum gets darker when exposed to heat. I’d like confirmation if this is a thing and if so an explanation of the process.

Another thing I think is worth mentioning is that when I ran my finger on the aluminum plate, even though my fingers or clean I was leaving a trace, as if I am finger-painting. I’m assuming this has something to do with the particles trapped beneath the so-called coating on the surface. Or do I have heard.

Please look at the image and tell me if my theory holds up or maybe something else is causing this weird thing.

The card is working just fine BTW.

Comment: Your questions is unclear. Please clarify your specific problem and make sure that your question contains the main question -from [review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/400160)

Comment: Does aluminum darken under heat. If so, explain the process.